# How to get all the childs using a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I need a list of all the childs. How would I go about getting only the child items.

here is how I get the childs

```
//lets get the parents along with the childs
var parents = from p in context.post
              where p.isDeleted == false && p.userid == new Guid(UserID)
                   let relatedchilds = from c in context.post
                                       where c.id == p.id
                                       select c.id
                   select new
                   {
                        p.id,
                        p.userid,
                        relatedchilds
                   }

//now lets get only the childs in the previous query
var childs = from c in parents
              select new
              {
                   c.relatedchilds.   //This is where my problem is
              }
```

How do I get only the relatedchilds in one column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `relatedchilds` is already a collection within each parent, which is itself a collection, you can use [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten the nested collections into a flat collection of id's:

```
var childs = parents.SelectMany( p => p.relatedchilds);
```

Alternatively in query format:

```
var childs = from p in parents
             from child in p.relatedchilds
             select child;
```